# Alternative in RequestMatcher

Tags: spring-security

does anybody have an idea how to get an "alternative" (OR) in RequestMatchers in Spring Security?

Basically, I would like to achieve the following

```
public class ApplicationWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAuthority("READONLY")
        //.or()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("REAL_USER");
}
```

so, require the user to either have the authority READONLY (if it's a GET request) or otherwise have the role REAL_USER (if it's not GET or the user does not have the authority READONLY)

thanks

Comment: yes, I've tried it. it doesn't work as desired - basically the filter matches first rule and requires user to have authority=READONLY. if he hasn't, request gets rejected, without trying out the second rule.

Comment: ok, this should work, thanks! you may add your solution as reply, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All matchers are OR conjuncted, but the first matching matcher is used. Hence, you have to configure each matcher completely.

Your modified code:

```java
public class ApplicationWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyAuthority("READONLY", "ROLE_REAL_USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("REAL_USER");
    }
```